# Как сбросить состояние QQuickView и загруженного в него QML-файла в начальное состояние?

Tags: webkit, webview, qt, c++, qml

Взгляните на этот простейший проект: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ctdcgrk0eqgq3a3/webview_test.tar.gz

Когда вы запускаете приложение, вы видите белое окно. Кликните на это окно и вы увидите броузер, в котором открыт Twitter. Кликните на белое окно еще раз и браузер будет закрыт, а его QQuickView будет уничтожен.

Итак, залогиньтесь в Твиттер. Потом уничтожьте броузер, кликнув еще раз на главное окно, а затем создайте его заново кликнув еще раз. Вы увидите, что вы до сих пор залогинены. Но мне нужно, чтобы броузер каждый раз открывался с разлогиненым пользователем (даже если тот установил флажок "Remember me"). Как сделать это? Как уничтожить все сохраненные данные и вернуть браузер в начальное состояние? Желательно, без удаления его каждый раз.

Вот основные части этого проекта:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

#include "container.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Container c;
    c.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**container.cpp**

```
#include "container.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QQmlContext>

Container::Container(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    mainFile = new QQuickView();

    browserExists = false;
}

Container::~Container()
{
    delete mainFile;
}

void Container::start()
{
    mainFile->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));

    connect(mainFile->rootObject(), SIGNAL(click()), this, SLOT(mainFileClicked()));

    mainFile->show();
}

void Container::mainFileClicked()
{
    if(!browserExists)
    {
        browser = new QQuickView();
        browser->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/browser.qml"));
        browser->rootContext()->setContextProperty("address", "http://twitter.com");

        browser->show();

        browserExists = true;
    }
    else
    {
        browser->hide();
        delete browser;

        browserExists = false;
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 320
    height: 240

    signal click();

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        onClicked:
        {
            click()
        }
    }
}
```

**browser.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtWebKit 3.0
import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0

Item {
    width: 640
    height: 480

    signal closeWindow();

    WebView
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: address
        experimental.preferences.privateBrowsingEnabled: true
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to reload qml file to QQuickView][1].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337493/how-to-reload-qml-file-to-qquickview

Comment: @falstaf
Я пробовал делать browser->engine()->clearComponentCache(); перед browser->setSource(); но это не помогает.
Установка пустых кукисов тоже не помогает

Comment: И удаление cookie browser->engine()->networkAccessManager()->setCookieJar(new QNetworkCookieJar()); тоже не помогает.